# Panda dataframe KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I set up a Pandas dataframe that works correctly for the first key `Rating` but does not work for the second key I try, `Company`. I get `KeyError 'Company'` when I run the script. I have no idea why I am getting an error. Below you will find the screenshot of relevant inspect elements page, the full error and my code.

[image: Inspect Element]

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Company'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 38, in <module>
    companies = (df['Company'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Company'
```

Script:

```
import codecademylib3_seaborn
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#leave out columns REF(3),Review Date (4),Company Location (6)

url = 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/beautifulsoup/cacao/index.html'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')


# table = soup.select('table#cacaoTable')
table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "cacaoTable" })
print(table)

columns = table.find('tr').find_all('td')
column_names = [c.string for c in columns]

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
l = []

for tr in table_rows:
  td = tr.find_all('td')
  row = [str(tr.get_text()).strip() for tr in td] #converting to python string object then use .strip() to clean 
  l.append(row)
   
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=column_names)
ratings = (df['Rating'])
print(ratings)




companies = (df['Company'])
```

Python newbie btw

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, I hope to be helpful

- **CODE**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


url = 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/beautifulsoup/cacao/index.html'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')


# Extract Table Html
table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "cacaoTable" })

# Extract Features
company=table.find_all(class_='Origin')
origin=table.find_all(class_='Company')
ref=table.find_all(class_='REF')
review=table.find_all(class_='ReviewDate')
cocoa_percent=table.find_all(class_='CocoaPercent')
location=table.find_all(class_='CompanyLocation')
rating=table.find_all(class_='Rating')
bean=table.find_all(class_='BeanType')
broad=table.find_all(class_='BroadBeanOrigin')

# Create Arrays in order to store data 
origin2=[]
company2=[]
ref2=[]
review2=[]
cocoa_percent2=[]
location2=[]
rating2=[]
bean2=[]
broad2=[]

for i in range(1,len(origin)):
    
    company2.append(company[i].text.replace('  ','').replace('\xa0\n','').strip())
    origin2.append(origin[i].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))
    ref2.append(ref[i].text)
    review2.append(review[i].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))
    cocoa_percent2.append(cocoa_percent[i].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))
    location2.append(location[i].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))
    rating2.append(rating[i].text)
    bean2.append(bean[i].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','').replace('\xa0',''))
    broad2.append(broad[i].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ',''))

# Columns
column1=company[0].text.replace('  ','').replace('\xa0\n','').replace('\n','').strip()
column2=origin[0].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
column3=ref[0].text
column4=review[0].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
column5=cocoa_percent[0].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
column6=location[0].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
column7=rating[0].text
column8=bean[0].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')
column9=broad[0].text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','')

columns = [column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9]


df_final={
    columns[1]:origin2,
    columns[0]:company2,
    columns[2]:ref2,
    columns[3]:review2,
    columns[4]:cocoa_percent2,
    columns[5]:location2,
    columns[6]:rating2,
    columns[7]:bean2,
    columns[8]:broad2
    
}

df_final=pd.DataFrame(df_final)
df_final.head(10)
```

- **OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I greatly appreciate the work you did. I was able to figure it out doing it my way, (column name was actually `companyxa0\n `  but I am also going to give it a shot doing it the way you've done here. I am new to this and I haven't figured out how I prefer doing it, so its very helpful to have this different way of doing it that you posted. Thanks again!!

Comment: you're welcome, If it was helpful don't forget to upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I was not using the correct column name when doing `companies = df(['Company'])` I was able to debug and find the true column name.
[image: column names]